# Can't redirect inside canvas, CodeIgniter

Tags: facebook, url, codeigniter, redirect, canvas

I am using [canvas](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#canvas) for application development and the [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeigniter#CodeIgniter)  framework.

I have a link in a view, `<a href='http://example.com/index.php/module/controller/action'>click here</a>` and I have a controller as:

```
public function index() {
    $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/sujeet216');
    $token        = $this->session->userdata('token');

    $response     = $this->fb_model->checkUser($token);
    if ($response->num_rows <= 0) {
        if($this->fb_model->insertUser($user_profile,$token)) {
            $this->load->view('intro',$user_profile);
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->load->view('index',$user_profile);
    }
}

public function intro2() {
    $this->load->view('intro2');
}
```

Whenever I click a link, it redirects to the index controller. How do I load `intro2` page from the second function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the app is trying to authenticate and Facebook redirects the app back to the callback URL that you have set. You have two options to combat this:

1. Use a library, for example the [PHP-SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk) and ensure you autoload it, this will ensure that the access_token isn't lost.
2. Ensure that the API is being called and the access_token is being passed from each controller.

I'd recommend going for option number 1 as it gives you much more flexability in relation to using the API once the user has authenticated against Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not routing the URL, `index.php/module/controller/action` goes to `index.php/controller/method/parameter`. Try redirecting to `index.php/controller/intro2`.